# Using \CodelineIndex alongside other indices in a dtx file

Tags: indexing, dtx, imakeidx

Is it possible (and if so, 'how?') to have multiple indices (via [`imakeidx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/imakeidx)) in the documentation for a package/class file, and include the codeline index and change log without completely redefinining `\CodelineIndex`, `\RecordChanges`, the `macro` environment, etc.?

I've been reading through the [`doc`](http://ctan.org/pkg/doc) source/documentation in an attempt to figure out if it would be possible to redefine the index commands themselves (so `\CodelineIndex` et al. wouldn't even need to be touched), but so far haven't found any useful information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Silly me; I was looking for the answer in the wrong place and just answered my own question.

**Answer** Use the `splitindex` option, eg. `\RequirePackage[splitindex]{imakeidx}`

`imakeidx` provides the `splitindex` option which (as you might expect) allows all index entries to be written to a single file, then split out by the `splitindex` script. This means that conflicting (or absent) macros like `\@indexfile` are still there, and everything works as expected.